# Keras «Powerful image classification with little data»: disparity between training and validation

Tags: image, performance, classification, keras

I followed [this post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) and first made it work on the dataset «Cats vs dogs». Then I substituted this set with my own images, which show the presence of an object vs the absence of that object. My dataset is even smaller than the one in [the post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html). I only have 496 images containing that object for training and 160 images with that object for validation. For the «absent» class I have numerous samples (without that object in an image).

So far I didn't try `class_weight` to tackle the imbalanced data problem. I just randomly choose 496 and 160 images without that object for training and validation, respectively. Basically, I do a two class image classification with a smaller dataset using the techniques in [this post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html). Thus I expected a worse performance in comparison due to the insufficient data. But the actual problem is that the performance is not convergent as shown in the figures.

Could you tell me possible reasons that lead to the unconvergence? I guess the problem is related to my dataset as the model works perfectly for «cats vs dogs». But I don't know how to address it. Are there any good techniques to make it convergent?

Thank you.

[image: VGG model]]

This performance plot is based on VGG16, keeping all layers up to fully connected layer and training a small fully connected layer with 256 neurons.

[image]
This performance plot is also based on VGG16, but using 128 neurons instead of 256 neurons. Also I set epochs to 80.

Based on the suggestions provided so far, I'm thinking to have a customized convnet model to fight the overfitting problem. But how to do this? One of my worries is that a model with fewer layers will downgrade the performance for training. Any guidelines to customize a good model for little data? Thank you.

Updates:

Now I think I know the half reason that leads to the unconvergent problem.  You know, Actually I only have 100+ images. The rest images are downloaded from Flickr. I thought those images having centric objects and better quality will work for the model. But later on I found they can not contribute to the accuracy and even worse the output class probabilities. After removing these downloaded images, the performance is bumping upward a little and the uncovergency is gone. Note I only use 64*2 images for training and 48*2 images for testing. Also I found the image augmentation could not improve the performance for my dataset. Without image augmentation, the training accuracy could reach 1. But if I add some image augmentation, the training accuracy is only around 85%. Did somebody have such experience? Why doesn't data augmentation always work? Because our specific dataset? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is working great, but it's "overfitting". It means it's capable of memorizing all your training data without really "thinking". That leads to great training results and bad test results.

Common ways to avoid overfitting are:

- More data - If you have little data, the chance of overfitting increases
- Less units/layers - Make the model less capable, so it will stop memorizing and start thinking.
- Add "dropouts" to your layers (something that randomly discards part of the results to prevent the model from being too powerful)

---

**Do more layers mean more power and performance?**

If by performance you mean capability of learning, yes. (If you mean "speed", no)

Yes, more layers mean more power. But too much power leads to overfitting: the model is so capable that it can memorize training data.

So there is an optimal point:

- A model that is not very capable will not give you the proper results (both training and test results will be bad)
- A model that is too capable will memorize the training data (excellent training results, but bad test results)
- A balanced model will learn the right things (good training and test results)

That's exactly why we use test data, it's data that is not presented for training, so the model doesn't learn from the test data.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. In fact, I couldn't get more data. So I will try your last two suggestions. One thing is that my understanding is more layers mean more power/better performance. If I use a smaller convnet, will that downgrade the performance? Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more details how exactly you trained? Francois` tutorial describes three ways (from scratch, pretrained only top layer, pretrained first convblocks?) What I find curious is that you have no convergence at all until epoch 18 or so. It might be helpful if you posted your full code.

Comment: @petezurich, Sorry for the unclarity. The performance plot I got is based on the code here(https://gist.github.com/fchollet/f35fbc80e066a49d65f1688a7e99f069). So it's the second step--pretrained only top layer, in the post.

Comment: @petezurich, actually the code in the repos has some bugs, but you could find the fixes in the discussions below the code

Comment: @ Daniel, I really appreciate your prompt  and excellent suggestions. I think my dataset is problematic. Let me explain my dataset in details. Hope you could help me analyze a little bit. I really have only around 200 images of that object(which is a tegu lizard). Those images have some duplication information since they are captured by camera. Probably only ~100 images are totally different. I think such a little data is definitely not enough for training. So I downloaded ~500 tegu lizard images from flickr and manually delete the images with person in it. After that I got 451 images.

Comment: Well... it's important that your images are in the same format as the cats and dogs. Normally they transform the images in values from 0 to 1, shaped in three channels and so. Did you treat those images properly to match the same format?

Comment: @Daniel, I extracted 45 images out of 205 real images, and together with 451 images downloaded from flickr. Thus I got 496 images for training. And I use the rest 160 images for validation. One thing worth mentioning is that the real images have both occlusion and background clutter problem. Thus I intendedly selected comparatively clear 45 images for training

Comment: Yes, I resized all these images to 1024 pixels, because with 224 pixels, the performance is just randomly guess---0.5

Comment: But did you care about the "range" (ex: from 0 to 1?)

Comment: There is a line of code--datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255) in it, I assume it takes care of the range to [0,1]

Comment: @Daniel, I also tried finetune Alexnet based on this post (https://rahulduggal2608.wordpress.com/2017/04/02/alexnet-in-keras/). The performance between training and validation still has a big gap. Do you mean I should build a convnet with fewer layers /fewer weight parameters to make the training curve close enough to validation curve? Is my understanding correct? If so, do you have any estimation using this little data what percentage is the optimal value for both curves to achieve? Also how many layers should my model use? Any references? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I mean that, make your model less powerful. But unfortunately I have no idea of good values. One thing, though, you mentioned you cutted people out. So, if you left a blank space in lizzard images, your model may be focusing on that very evident feature that happens only in lizzard photos.

Comment: Oh, I didn't cut people out. I just remove the image with person from the dataset.

Comment: Yes, the convnet may consider a blank space as a feature. Thank you. One more question, could I build a model just by removing several layers of the VGG or Alexnet? In this way, I could still do transferring learning and reuse some weight parameters. Or it's not reasonable to do in this way so that I have to rebuild everything from scratch?

Comment: You may try reducing the last part only, the final dense layers. Use less `units`, for instance, or even less dense layers.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post and added a new plot that is based on a smaller connected layer with only 128 neurons. But the overfitting problem is also severe. Any other things that I could try?